# Writing text to the canvas via a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, canvas

I understand how to get text onto a canvas in JavaScript outside of a function, but putting the code in a function seems to break everything

**Example:**

```
var c = document.getElementById("APICanvas");
var canvas = c.getContext("2d");
canvas.font('20px Times New Roman);
canvas.fillText("Hello, world!", 20, 20);
```

This results in `"Hello, world!"` at `(20,20)` on the `canvas`, but

```
function text(text,x,y) {
    var c = document.getElementById("APICanvas");
            var canvas = c.getContext("2d");
            canvas.font('20px Times New Roman);
            canvas.fillText(text,x,y);
    }

text("Hello, world!",20,20);
```

This results in nothing showing up on the `canvas`.

I don't know why using this inside a function doesn't work and am seriously confused.

Comment: are missing a closing `'` at the end of `canvas.font`?

Comment: there is a single quote missing at the end of `canvas.font('20px Times New Roman);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`font` is a property not function. You have to set the property with assignment operator. You have also missed the closing `'` at the end of the property string value.

Change

```
canvas.font('20px Times New Roman);
```

To

```
canvas.font = '20px Times New Roman';
```

```js
function text(text,x,y) {
  var c = document.getElementById("APICanvas");
  var canvas = c.getContext("2d");
  canvas.font = '20px Times New Roman';
  canvas.fillText(text,x,y);
}

text("Hello, world!",20,20);
```

```html
<canvas id="APICanvas"></div>
```

Comment: @Metype, if the answer solves your question then you could accept the answer by *clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green*.....thanks